# Можно ли сделать образ с флешки?

Tags: образ

Есть флешка с установщиком Windows. Нужно сделать диск с установщиком. При создании флешки, там нужно было сделать загрузочный раздел. Думаю, если просто скопировать содержимое флешки на диск, что-нибудь может пойти не так.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ultraiso мне помогало в таких задачах.

Answer (score -1):

Если я правильно Вас понял, то у Вас есть рабочий вариант загрузочной флешки с Windows. Если так, то при переносе данных на оптический диск ни каких дополнительных действий не требуется. В этом можно убедиться просто создав образ с помощью программы для записи дисков, или обычным rar-архиватором, и попробовать запустить установку на виртуальной машине - virtualbox.